# Get full rendered Wordpress page with WPML via REST API

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api, wpml

I've made a Laravel-Wordpress connection for a project. For this connection, I use the Worpdress REST API.
I'm able to get specific pages from Laravel with the header and footer from Wordpress via API (for a uniform look) and other pages comes completely from Wordpress. Big benefit is, that Wordpress pages can be edited with the pretty user-friendly Wordpress backend while other pages can be custom coded in Laravel.

To achieve this, I have added some new API endpoints to retrieve the rendered header / footer and a complete page:

```
add_action('rest_api_init', function () {
    // add 'rendered_page' member with complete HTML for requested page
    register_rest_field(
        'page',
        'content',
        array(
            'get_callback' => 'by_render_page_content',
            'update_callback' => null,
            'schema' => null,
        )
    );
    // add new endpoint for getting header and footer
    register_rest_route('eeg/v1', '/headerandfooter', array(
        'methods' => 'GET,POST',
        'callback' => 'get_page_header_and_footer',
    ));
});
```

The callbacks look like this: (i.e. for the complete page)

```
if (isset($request['language'])) {
    do_action('wpml_switch_language', $request['language']);
}
$file = THEME_DIR . '/single.php';
ob_start();
include $file;
return ob_get_clean();
```

As you can see, I'm checking for a `language` parameter and set the current language of the WPML plugin with `wpml_switch_language` hook.
This seems to work 'a little bit'. So, for example, the language switcher shows the correct current language.

The problem is, in the main menu: All links are showing to default language. For example if currently selected language is english, the links should look like `mydomain.com/en/requestedpage`. But all links go to the default `mydomain.com/requestedpage`. Also the `<html lang>` parameter is set to the default language, not to the requested. And also the `<link hreflang>` tags from WPML are missing.

If I access the page via the Wordpress Frontend (which is hosted at a subdomain), everything is working correctly.
So I think, I have to set the requested language somewhere else or have to call some WPML 'prepare' hooks or something like that, to make this work. Maybe also the `include './single.php';` is not the right way to do this.

Any hint is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I could fix it by myself.
The solution was to create a translated menu with WPML.
In Wordpress frontend, the links in the menus are localized also without an extra translated menu. But for this scenario with the REST API, a translated menu is necessary.